# Arraybindcount is not a member of System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand. is thrown while compiling itself

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle11g, oracle10g, odp.net

```
Dim cn As New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)
cn.Open()

TruncateTable("table", cn)

Dim cmd As New OracleClient.OracleCommand()
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = "package.table_bulk_insert"


cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_DIV_ID", DbType.String, DIV_ID, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_DIV_NAME", DbType.String, DIV_NAME, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_DIV_OBJ_ID", DbType.String, DIV_OBJ_ID, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_SITE_ID", DbType.String, SITE_ID, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_SITE_OBJ_ID", DbType.String, SITE_OBJ_ID, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_UE_SITE_NAME", DbType.String, UE_SITE_NAME, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_UE_SITE_LOCATION", DbType.String, UE_SITE_LOCATION, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_UE_SITE_COUNTRY", DbType.String, UE_SITE_COUNTRY, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_GEOGRAPHY", DbType.String, GEOGRAPHY, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_FEED_ID", DbType.String, FEED_ID, ParameterDirection.Input))
cmd.Parameters.Add(makeOraParamter("ins_IS_BASELINE", DbType.String, IS_BASELINE, ParameterDirection.Input))


cmd.ArrayBindCount = array_size + 1
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You used the tag "ODP.NET", but you are not using it, you are using OracleClient. Could that be your mistake?

OracleClient does not appear to support it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57a59fba-09e2-46cb-a072-6706b3ec5131/array-binding?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Otherwise just change your app to use Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Comment: Thanks for your response Shay,the application was built with 10g oracle client dll. now I am trying to upgrade to 11 g and I have changed the reference from 10g dll to 11g. The problem as soon as add 11g dll, it starts saying that Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client is not found or has no public member and forces me to correct OracleConnection to OracleClient.OracleConnection.

Comment: Yeah, so you need to focus on that issue and forget about this one, since you have no intention of using OracleClient anyway. Perhaps reinstall the 11g ODP.NET.